# using dataframe.apply to call unique function on each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, apply

I've been wanting to make the following work so as to have a simple story for executing `pandas.DataFrame.someColumnName.unique()` function on each column within a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
df.apply(func=unique, axis=0)  # error NameError: name 'unique' is not defined
```

Is there some trick i'm overlooking to get this working or an alternative solution given the following to do something similar but using `type()` function on each column in `pandas.DataFrame` works.

```
df.apply(func=lambda x: type(x[0]), axis=0)
```

Note that i have been able to make the following work but doesn't seem to be a way in python to make single line for loops and i find the apply statement a better self documenting implementation.

```
for col in df.columns: 
    df[col].unique()
```

Comment: Motivation is when doing exploratory data analysis [eda] on a new dataset I want to not only output types associated with each column but also a listing of the unique values that exist in each column.  This will define next steps needed to implement data wrangling code that deals with holes/NaN values and garbage values.

Comment: Yeah pandas does not like it when the result of the function passed to apply is a different size for different columns in the dataframe.... which I assume is very likely happening with your data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unique` is not a registered function in global environment, you can use `set` for this purpose:

```
df.apply(set)
```

Or if using `unique`, refer it from `pandas`, also you'd better convert the result to a list, as there is no guarantee all columns contain same number of unique elements:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.unique(x).tolist())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a one liner loop, you can do:

```
{e:df[e].unique() for e in df.columns}
```

Comment: This approach prints the df['colname'].unique() output for each column all merged together vs each output separated by a crlf. The "for col in df.columns: df[col].unique()" one liner loop syntax, and two line syntax with the call to execute on each loop indented, both I find require executing any line of python script code following it in order for it to execute the loop.  I found I could use the no-op "pass" call to satisfy that need. Is that a well known for loop expected matter?